# Check docker container status if it is running using python

Tags: python, docker, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a repo in github and there are shared containers(folders) in the repo. I need to check if the shared containers are running by using python.
This is what I have tried:

```
import docker

DOCKER_CLIENT = docker.DockerClient(base_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock")
RUNNING = "running"

def is_running(container_name):
    container = DOCKER_CLIENT.containers.get(container_name)
    container_state = container.attrs["State"]
    container_is_running = container_state["Status"] == RUNNING
    return container_is_running


my_container_name = "myfolder1"
print(is_running(my_container_name))
```

If I run this script in VS code IDE terminal, Im not getting any errors or results.
Am I missing anything here? Can anyone suggest any other approach for this

Comment: Are you sure it's running?  You should get output from the print one way or another.  What do you see?

Comment: @w08r - Its just giving me a blank new line in the terminal

Comment: I think we are missing some information.  That should either print `True` or `False` or throw an exception if the container is not found.  How are you running it?  Can you add some simple `print` statement to verify it's running properly.

Comment: Tried with print statement as well, but no luck.
Running it from VS code terminal and ran with powershell also. Getting a blank line in both of them

Comment: @w08r: I'm getting this error now: AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'

Comment: this seems like an issue https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/2547. it is an old one. Try to update the version of the module